# Permutation and combination/ probability

Tags: probability

If you have 7 white socks and 9 black socks in a drawer, how many socks do  you have to pull out blindly in order to ensure that you have a matching pair ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! There are quite a number of really similar questions on the site, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325149/number-of-socks-to-guarantee-getting-a-matching-pair?rq=1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336628/from-a-bag-containing-10-pairs-of-socks-how-many-must-a-person-pull-out-to-en?rq=1 and most importantly this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124144/the-drawer-has-m-different-colored-socks-what-is-the-least-amount-of-socks-i-th. What did you not understand about the answers to these questions?

Comment: I decided to delete my answer after reflecting Hrodelberts comment.

Comment: If 'ensure' means absolutely certain, then it is a logic problem, not a probability problem. Are there any purple socks in the drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $W:="\text{white sock}"$ and $B:="\text{black sock}"$.

Let's pull:

- 1. pull: obviously, we can not ensure.
- 2. pull: cases:
         $$(B,W),(W,B),(B,B),(W,W).$$
         Due to $(W,B)$ and $(B,W)$ we can not ensure.
- 3. pull: cases:
      $$(B,W,W),(B,W,B),(W,B,W),(W,B,B),(B,B,W),(B,B,B),(W,W,W),(W,W,B).$$
     We did it.

Remark: since we have 7 white socks and 9 black socks we don't have to worry about missing socks in our first 3 rounds.